# Alternative to mapping over the same array twice for two components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a navbar that needs the names of an array of objects (will be JSON later, I'm just mocking it up.)

Then I have a bunch of accordion components that use the same array of objects.

These are in the same parent component (Plans.js, which is a React Router page). The parent handles the openAccordion state. I feel like it's ridiculous to use two maps, but because of the nature of map, I don't see a good way to have all the accordions be in one container and all the navbars in another.

```
<nav className="accordion-navbar">
        {
          plans.map((plan) => {
            return(
              <AccordionListItem setOpenAccordion={setOpenAccordion} openAccordion={openAccordion} plan={plan}/>
            )
          })
        }
      </nav>
      
        {
          plans.map((plan) => {
            return(
              <Accordion setOpenAccordion={setOpenAccordion} openAccordion={openAccordion} plan={plan} setState={setState} state={state}/>
            )
          })
        }
```

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. If it was repeated like 4 or more times, I could see refactoring to be worth it, but the current approach is fine with only 2

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, looping twice to do one thing in each iteration vs looping once and doing two things per iteration is the same number of things. Prioritize ease of extensibility and ease of reading over such performance concerns.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of showing all options, you could do it with a single loop, but I'd argue (similar to the comments on your question) that the two-loop solution is easier to read/ comprehend:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function App(){
  const squares = []
  const cubes = []

  data.forEach(no => {
    squares.push(<li>{no * no}</li>);
    cubes.push(<li>{no * no * no}</li>);
  })

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ul>{squares}</ul>
      <ul>{cubes}</ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Alternatively this would also be possible, but might be even less readable:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function App() {
  const { squares, cubes } = data.reduce(
    ({ squares, cubes }, no) => ({
      squares: [...squares, <li>{no * no}</li>],
      cubes: [...cubes, <li>{no * no * no}</li>],
    }),
    { squares: [], cubes: [] }
  );

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ul>{squares}</ul>
      <ul>{cubes}</ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

One could certainly also make a single-loop solution with `map()` work, but it doesn't really make things better.

Comment: Even if I stick with something like my original code, I really appreciated this answer bc I hadn't really thought about things like that. Thanks!